# How to return comma-delimited string of range of cells in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using Google Sheets and writing a custom function that takes in a range of cells as parameter and returns a string that adds a delimiting comma to the contents of the cell.

For example, we have a range `B1:B2` where cell B1 contains `"B1_contents"` and cell B2 contains `"B2_contents"`. The function should return `"B1_contents, B2_contents"`.

How can this be done in Google Sheets using Google Apps Script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following:

```js
function rangeToStringSep(range, sep) {
  return range.toString().split(',').join(sep);
}
```

Use:

```js
=rangeToStringSep(B1:B3; ", ")
```

**UPDATE**

```js
function rangeToStringSep1(range, sep) {
  return range.join(sep);
}
```

[image]

Comment: no need to split before join, you can directly write .join(sep)

Comment: @Sergeinsas: That's right when the range is B1:B3, but if the range is wider, for example, A1:B3 the expected string is not obtained unless you use the `toString()` and `split()` functions.

Comment: Mmmm... I checked without the split and it works also... in what condition is this really necessary ?

Comment: mmmh, ok I see, I didn't really care about the spaces...thanks

Answer (score 1):

have you tried something like that ?

```
function toCommaSepStrings(values){
  return values.toString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Why is it you do not need to explicitly state that comma is to be used for delimiting?

Comment: Comma is default value, you can also use join() and specify any other junction character